# Run native sql query in JPA give difference result vs when run the same query directly in SQL tool

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a native query like this:

```
WITH SOURCE_A AS (
SELECT a.ID FROM A a
WHERE a.SOME_THING > 1000
),
SOURCE_B AS (
    SELECT b.ID FROM B b
    INNER JOIN A a ON a.B_ID = b.ID
    WHERE a.ID IN (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_A)
    AND call_to_a_procedure(b.SOME_THING) = 1
),
SOURCE_C AS (
    SELECT c.ID FROM C c
    INNER JOIN B b ON b.C_ID = c.ID
    WHERE b.ID IN (SELECTT * FROM SOURCE_B)
    AND call_to_a_procedure(c.SOME_THING) = 1
)
SELECT re.CODE FROM RESULT re
INNER JOIN A a ON a.ID = re.ID_A
WHERE a.ID IN (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_A)

UNION

SELECT re.CODE FROM RESULT re
INNER JOIN B b ON b.ID = re.ID_B
WHERE b.ID IN (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_B)

UNION

SELECT re.CODE FROM RESULT re
INNER JOIN C c ON c.ID = re.ID_C
WHERE c.ID IN (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_C)
```

When I reun this query with `query.getResultList()` . Only the result of :

```
SELECT re.CODE FROM RESULT re
INNER JOIN A a ON a.ID = re.ID_A
WHERE a.ID IN (SELECT * FROM SOURCE_A)
```

is returned. The two UNION are ignored. But if I run the query directly in SQL tool like Oracle SQL developer or DBeaver, I get full UNION result.

JPA just silently ignore the UNION part, no error or exception.

**UPDATE:** It maybe because the call to `call_to_a_procedure` didn't work in jpa because if i remove the call to procedure, I can get the expected result.

Comment: Did you run this query as a _native_ query?  If not, then those CTEs for certain would not work.

Comment: Can you show the code around the native query?

Comment: Please show the generated SQL statement

Comment: The sql I posted is the generated sql, I copy it from the log and paste to Oracle SQL developer to run.

@TimBiegeleisen what is CTEs? The query is run by calling `getResultList()`

Comment: Hibernate does not use common table expressions AFAIK (because not all supported database vendors use them).  So, this looks like raw SQL you were running directly on Oracle, and not what was being run from JPA.

Comment: How can I get the query that was run by JPA? The query I posted is what I got from JBoss server's log which is the same as the query string I pass to `createNativeQuery` function.